# Broadcast ARP weirdness

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, arp

we a running a router on a custom Linux box. Kernel is 3.14.14.

What happens is that when you arping the router in broadcast only mode is the router has a verey slow response time:

```
# arping -b -c 50 -w 100000 -I em1.3069 -s 77.46.0.181 77.46.0.1
ARPING 77.46.0.1 from 77.46.0.181 em1.3069
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  773.358ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  667.217ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  403.133ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  284.954ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  243.775ms
```

BUT if you do not use -b flag:

```
# arping -c 50 -w 100000 -I em1.3069 -s 77.46.0.181 77.46.0.1
ARPING 77.46.0.1 from 77.46.0.181 em1.3069
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  189.149ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  0.773ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  0.815ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  0.760ms
Unicast reply from 77.46.0.1 [78:2B:CB:49:00:CA]  0.798ms
Sent 5 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 5 response(s)
```

Only the first reply is affected (the broadcast one). Anybody has an idea what might be going on here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry to be a necrophiliac, but i have a similar question (with a switch instead of a linux box).